# Happy Birthday, Don!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

My friend Johan de Ruiter has made a nice puzzle for Donald Knuth's Birthday. The numbers indicate how many connections that candle has. Can you solve it?

Original link: https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/pi_hamilton_maze.png

[image]

Comment: Are we to assume you can't visit a candle more than once, or just that you can't extinguish it more than once?

Comment: you can't visit it more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

It's actually quite straightforward to solve; at each step

> you identify a vertex where there's no choice given the other information you already have. The only slight subtlety is that at one point I had to reason as follows: I already have 6-4-8 or 8-6-4, so 5 can't connect to both. (At that point there were 3 things the 5 could connect to.)